# List Taxonomies: Don't list taxonomy if it has no post - depending on custom post-meta?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, categories

This might be complicated to explain and I don't know if there is a solution to that!?

I have a custom-post-type named "wr_event" and a hierarchical custom-taxonomy named "event_type". The custom-post-type has a meta-box for `event_date` and all posts associated with this post-type are sorted by this `event_date`. I have one special condition in my loop to query if the `event_date` has already taken place - in that case it's not shown but only listed in my archives.

Just like you can use `wp_list_categories()` I wrote a custom function that lists all taxonomy-terms exactly the same way.

And now my question:

When I use my custom `wr_list_taxonomy()` function it lists all taxonomies that have a post associated with it. Just like `wp_list_categories()` lists only the categories that have a post associated with it. If there would be a taxonomy-term that doesn't have posts it wouldn't be listed.

I wonder if it's somehow possible to "exclude" a taxonomy-term or simply not list it if all posts associated with it have an `event_date` that has already taken place.

Sounds complicated right?

So I have this function that works like a charm.

```
function wr_list_taxonomy($taxonomy, $orderby, $hierarchical) {
    $show_count   = 0;
    $pad_counts   = 0;
    $title        = '';

    $args = array(
      'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
      'orderby'      => $orderby,
      'show_count'   => $show_count,
      'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
      'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
      'title_li'     => $title
    );

    return wp_list_categories( $args );
}
```

It lists all terms and only lists them if posts are in them. However I have posts ("events" in my case) in all taxonomy-terms, but have terms whose events are all over.

And if the "events" in a term are all over (and therefore the term-page doesn't list anything as I wrote above because I filter them by todays date) I don't want this function `wr_list_taxonomy()` to print this term.

Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`wp_get_object_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) which takes an array of post IDs, a taxonomy, and some optional arguments to determine what to return.

So, you'd use `get_posts()` to query future events, build an array of IDs, and then pass that array to `wp_get_object_terms()`.

Comment: Awesome, perfect. Worked like a charm!